# XSLT add a parent with ascending numbers and grouping with attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, numbers, grouping

I have a bit of XML which I need to add a parent node to i.e. node1, node2, node3 etc. This I  then need to also group with other nodes:

Original XML:

```
<parentnode>
<childnode attribute="option.a.b.1">
</childnode>
<childnode attribute="option.a.b.2">
</childnode>
<childnode attribute="option.a.b.1">
</childnode>
<childnode attribute="option.a.b.2">
</childnode>
<childnode attribute="option.a.b.3">
</childnode>
<childnode attribute="option.a.b.1">
</childnode>
<childnode attribute="option.a.b.2">
</childnode>
</parentnode>
```

Desired XML:

```
<parentnode>
<row0>
<childnode attribute="option.a.b.1">
</childnode>
<childnode attribute="option.a.b.2">
</childnode>
</row0>
<row1>
<childnode attribute="option.a.b.1">
</childnode>
<childnode attribute="option.a.b.2">
</childnode>
<childnode attribute="option.a.b.3">
</childnode>
</row1>
<row2>
<childnode attribute="option.a.b.1">
</childnode>
<childnode attribute="option.a.b.2">
</childnode>
</row2>
</parentnode>
```

option.a.b.* the * could be any number I just need it to start a new row every time option.a.b.1 appears. I'm not even sure if this is this possible in XSLT?

Comment: Well with XSLT 2.0 there is `for-each-group group-starting-with`. So use an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 and it is easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just need it to start a new row every time option.a.b.1 appears. I'm
>   not even sure if this is this possible in XSLT?

XSLT - even XSLT 1.0 - is a Turing-complete language, so yes, it *is* possible. If you are using XSLT 1.0, try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="k" match="childnode[not(@attribute='option.a.b.1')]" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::childnode[@attribute='option.a.b.1'][1])" />

<xsl:template match="/parentnode">
    <xsl:copy> 
        <xsl:for-each select="childnode[@attribute='option.a.b.1']">
            <xsl:element name="row{position()-1}">
                <xsl:copy-of select=". | key('k', generate-id())"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Note**: you could have figured this out by adapting the answer I gave you here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26397156/3016153

Answer (score 1):

Assuming an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 or XmlPrime or AltovaXML you can use

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="parentnode">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="childnode" group-starting-with="childnode[@attribute = 'option.a.b.1']">
                <row>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
                </row>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

I have intentionally not number the row elements as it results in a poor format in my view, if you really need that then use

```
<xsl:template match="parentnode">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="childnode" group-starting-with="childnode[@attribute = 'option.a.b.1']">
            <xsl:element name="row{position() - 1}">
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I attempted to work this, but was having issues with my transformer. Thanks though!